# How to change the way MotionLayout animates view visibility

Tags: android, visibility, android-motionlayout

Default MotionLayout view visibility animation is proportional scaling of view's size.
Not even scaling of resulting image, but actual View size changes.

On TextView this causes text realigning, so it jumps on every frame.

Is there a way to change that behaviour and instead, for example, change only height of the view?

I need exactly view visibility animation. Just animating view's height won't work as other views can have `layout_goneMargin`, view itself can have margins, and finally, view can simply have optimizations for GONE visibility that I don't want to miss out on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Visibility has 3 possible: values visible, invisible and gone

1. Visible - obvious
2. invisible - The space occupied by the view is unchanged the view is not rendered
3. gone - The view's width and
   height are 0;

The animation in MotionLayout must end in one of those 3 states.
You can manipulate how it gets there with keyframes.

**example**

If you are animating *visible* to *gone* but you want it to be a image scale effect
add a KeyAttribut to scale the image 0 at frame 99 but use a keyPosition to hold the size unchanged to frame 99.

```
    <KeyFrameSet>
       <KeyPosition
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/view"
           motion:framePosition="99"
           motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
           motion:percentX="0"
           motion:percentY="0"
           motion:sizePercent="0" />
       <KeyAttribute
           motion:motionTarget="@+id/view"
           motion:framePosition="100"
           android:scaleX="0"
           android:scaleY="0" />
   </KeyFrameSet>
```

- **KeyPosition** would retard the change in the position and size of the view till the end.
- **KeyAttribute** would apply a view view transform scaling to 0x0 at the end

Many Many effects that could be added with KeyAttributes are described in this [video](https://youtu.be/jUm_AkH_mAQ)

Comment: Nice Explaination.